# A module is both left artinian and left noetherian,but it is neither right artinian nor noetherian,

Tags: modules

I am reading Rings and Categories of Modules by Frank W.Aderson,on 130 pages.
It ssys,the ring R of all 2$\times$2 upper triangular matrices 
\begin{Bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & \gamma \end{Bmatrix}

with a,b$\in$R and $\gamma \in$Q is both left artinian and left noetherian,but it is neither right artinian nor right noetherian.

I can't prove it is not right artinian or right noetherian.

At the same time,I also can't undestand why it is both left artinian an right noetherian. Beacuse I even can't determine all submodule'form.For example thers are some obviously shape:
\begin{Bmatrix} a_1 & b_1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{Bmatrix} \begin{Bmatrix} a_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{Bmatrix}\begin{Bmatrix} 0 & b_1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{Bmatrix}\begin{Bmatrix} 0 & b_1 \\ 0 & \gamma \end{Bmatrix}
but there are also other forms :\begin{Bmatrix} b_1 & b_1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{Bmatrix}
So I can't deremine all the submodules'forms.
I want someone can give me some help,thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ and consider
$$
I_U=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & x \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}:x\in U\right\}
$$
This is obviously closed under addition. Moreover
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & x \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & \gamma \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & x\gamma \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\in I_U
$$
Hence $I_U$ is a right ideal.

Clearly, $U\subset U'$ implies $I_U\subset I_{U'}$.

Is $\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ an artinian or noetherian module?

Comment: Can you explain why it is left artinian and left noetherian?

Comment: @guojm Try and classify the left ideals; therea are just a few.

Comment: Dear @egreg, using your argument, I could find explicitly a non-stationary ascending chain, but I couldn't find a non-stationary descending chain. Could you help me to get one, please?

Comment: @rgm If you find an infinite linearly independent set of real numbers, then you have both chains: consider $1,\pi,\pi^2,\dotsc$