# Proving that this kind of matrix ring is left Noetherian but not right Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, extension-field, noetherian

I'm trying to prove that a matrix ring of the form $\begin{pmatrix} R & R\\ 0 & Q \end{pmatrix}$ where $R/Q$ is an infinite degree field extension, is left Noetherian, but not right Noetherian. I was first looking at a concrete example, e.g. $\begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R}\\ 0 & \mathbb{Q} \end{pmatrix}$ which is also discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249784/a-module-is-both-left-artinian-and-left-noetherian-but-it-is-neither-right-artin).

I think I have a solution for one part of the problem: If the extension $ R/Q$is of infinite degree, it means that there is an infinite sequence of field extensions $Q<K_1<K_2<…<R$. Looking at these $K_i$-s as $Q$-vector subspaces of $R$, using the construction given in the linked example, we get an infinite chain of right ideals, which means that it cannot be right Noetherian.

UPDATE: I think what I don't see right now is why such rings are left Noetherian. I think it would be convenient to tackle this using the fact that a module $M$ is (left) Noetherian iff for a submodule $N\leq M$, both $N$ and $M/N$ are (left) Noetharian.

Comment: Well, what difficulty do you have generalizing from that example?

Comment: To be fair, the solution there is only a hint in one direction. But still you should be able to use it to prove that same direction here...

Comment: There are also [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/159046/29335) that explain how to classify all left and right ideals of such rings.

Comment: If $R/Q$ is of infinite degree, it means that there is an infinite sequence of field extensions $Q < K_1 < K_2 <\ldots < R$. Looking at these $K_i$-s as $Q$-vector subspaces of $R$, using the construction given in the linked example, we get an infinite chain of right ideals, which means that it cannot be right Noetherian. Is that correct?

Comment: @sicmath Don't just put guesswork in a comment: take those thoughts and formalize them and put them into the post!

Comment: @sicmath I also think the idea in your update is worth pursuing.  After all, it does reduce the problem to a question about two other modules which might be simpler.